# Compare String to Arrays.asList values with if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, fxml

I'm using FXML to create a user interface.
There's a TextField which can be filled in, and a Button to be clicked.

When clicking on the button, the text that has been filled in should be read and compared to a List.

If the TextField contains characters that are equal to a value in the List, then a certain String should be displayed in a Text field on the same user interface.

```
public class FXMLController {

      @FXML TextField input
      @FXML private Text actionContains

      @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

             List<String> n1 = Arrays.asList("44606", "44613", "44615", "44619"}

             String getInput = input.getText();

             if(Arrays.asList(n1).contains(getInput)) {
                  actionContains.setText("CONTAINS");
             } else {
                  actionContains.setText("DOES NOT CONTAIN");
             }
     }
}
```

It's not a problem to run the code. The String getInput's value equals the input text, but the result of the if statement is always "DOES NOT CONTAIN".
The entered text is for example "**44606**621".

I've already cut off the last three characters in order to have a String which is equal or not to a List value (so equals in stead of contains), but this does nothing to the result.

Comment: A `List` of `List`s would never contain a `String`....

Comment: `n1` is already a `List`, why are you using `Arrays.asList` on it *again*?

Comment: `n1.contains(getInput)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for the string within every element of the array instead of looking for it within the array.

So replace your code by this

```
public class FXMLController { 
@FXML TextField input 
@FXML private Text actionContains 
@FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) { 
List<String> n1 = Arrays.asList("44606", "44613", "44615", "44619"}
String getInput = input.getText();

for(String s : n1) { 
  if(getinput.contains(s)) { 
      actionContains.setText("CONTAINS"); 
   } else { 
       actionContains.setText("DOES NOT CONTAIN"); 
   } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are putting it into arrayList twice so instead of arrayList it becomes arrayList of List.

```
List<String> n1 = Arrays.asList("44606", "44613", "44615", "44619"}


Arrays.asList(n1); <--- makes it into [["44606", "44613", "44615", "44619"]]
```

Change the if condition

```
 if(Arrays.asList(n1).contains(getInput)) {
...
```

to

```
 if(n1.contains(getInput)) {
```

Comment: I've changed it into

´List<String> n1 = new ArrayList<String>();

  n1.add("44606");

  n1.add("44613");

  n1.add("44615");´

And changed changed the if condition:

if(n1.contains(getInput)) {

But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code:

```
List<String> n1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    n1.add("44606");
    n1.add("44615");

String getInput = input.getText();
String cutInput = getInput.substring(0,5);

if (n1.contains(cutInput) {
    actionContains.setText("CONTAINS");
} else {
    actionsContains.setText("DOES NOT CONTAIN");
}
```

Changing the input to match the List values' number of characters results in a working if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the list and search if the word contains any of the element in the list, not other way around. The correct algorithm would be

```
 public void testW(){
    boolean flag = testContains(Arrays.asList("44606", "44613", "44615", "44619"),"44606621");
    System.out.println(flag);
    if(flag){
        actionContains.setText("CONTAINS");
    } else {
        actionContains.setText("DOES NOT CONTAIN");
    }
}

private boolean testContains(List<String> list, String word){
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(word.contains(list.get(i))){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```